# Can you configure mod_proxy as a reverse proxy cache?

Tags: apache, caching, reverse-proxy

I can configure mod_proxy to be a forward proxy cache and I can configure it to be a reverse proxy.  Is there any way to configure it to be a reverse proxy cache? I haven't had any luck with that yet.

Comment: You;d have better luck at http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2):

Using mod_proxy, Apache can function either as a forward proxy or a reverse proxy.  It does not function as a cache unless you specifically enable mod_cache too.  Once mod_cache is enabled, it should transparently handle caching of proxied content too.  The module is labeled **experimental**.

See [the mod_cache doc page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do what you ask (see for example Roshan's answer), but I would also suggest that you look at a dedicated reverse HTTP proxy: [Varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/).

Varnish is very efficient, much more so than Apache.